# Updating stock count using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm coding a purchase system for a website. I have pages for different products, on which the user can click a purchase button which sends them to the purchase page, the link to the purchase page includes the variables of the item so that I can display their order details on the purchase page.

One of the variables is $item_stock_count. I have a "Buy" button on the purchase page which reduces the stock variable by 1, then executes a MySQLi query that updates the stock value in the inventory table of my database. The problem is that the stock only reduces the FIRST time I click the Buy button, if I press the button after the stock does not change. The query is still exectuted but no rows are affected.

I reduce the stock variable after "if(isset($_POST['Buy']))", so surely every time the button is pressed the code inside that if statement should take effect.

**Purchase Page:**

```
<?php
$item_name = $_GET['item_name'];                  
$item_code = $_GET['item_code'];
$item_price = $_GET['item_price'];
$item_stock_count = $_GET['item_stock_count'];

$promo_approved = false;
$discount;
$_SESSION['item_price'];

//Product purchase table//
echo 
"<table>",
    "<tr>",
        "<th>Title</th>",
        "<th>Item Price</th>",
        "<th>Item Code</th>",
    "</tr>",
    "<tr>",
        "<th> $item_name  </th>",
        "<th> $item_price </th>",
        "<th> $item_code </th>",
    "</tr>",
"</table>";


//Is the login variable set? error prevention//
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
    //Is the customer logged in?//
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        //Is the product in stock?//

            //Connect to db//
            $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root')
            or die ("Failed to connect to MySQL Database:" . mysqli_connect_error);         

            $db = mysqli_select_db($connect, 'sm17977')
            or die("Could not open the Database");

            if($item_stock_count > 0){
            //If Buy button has been clicked//
                if(isset($_POST['Buy'])){
                    //Reduce stock count by 1//

                    //Stock reduction query//
                    $reduce_stock = 
                    "update inventory
                    set item_stock_count = $item_stock_count
                    where item_code = '$item_code'";

                    mysqli_query($connect, $reduce_stock);

                    echo "</br>Stock Count: " . $item_stock_count;
                    $item_stock_count = $item_stock_count - 1;

                    //Did the query update the stock?//
                    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) == 1){
                        echo "</br>Stock Updated.</br>";
                        echo "</br>New Stock Count: " . $item_stock_count;
                    }
                    //If the query did not update the stock//
                    else{
                        echo "</br> Failed to update stock.";
                        echo mysqli_error($connect);
                        echo "</br>New Stock Count: " . $item_stock_count;
                    }
                }
            }
        //If the item is not in stock//
        else{
            echo
            "<script>
                    alert('Item currently unavailable.');
            </script>";
        }
    }
    //If the user isn't logged in//
    else {
        echo
        "<p>You must be logged in to make purchases.</p>";
    }               
}
?>
            </br></br>
            <form method = "POST">
                </br><p>Promotional Code:</p>
                <input id = "code" type = "text" name = "promo" />
                </br>
                <input name = "Buy" value = "Buy" type = "submit" id = 'purchase_btn' <?php if($_SESSION['loggedin'] == false){ ?> disabled <?php }?>/>
            </form>

</html>
```

I've also tried moving around the code which reduces the variable, but nothing changes, as I'm sure the reduce code must be at the start of the Buy button if statement so that the query isupdated accurately, I'm not sure how to fix this.

So in short, the buy button only reduces the stock count variable the first time, subsequent clicks after that do not change the stock.

I'm sure I'm probably missing something really simple, and I apprecite any help.

EDIT: This code is part of an assignment in which I cannot use frameworks and is not intended for professional use, should have made that clear.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Having database connection code dumped in the middle of a table is really not a sustainable development model. If you don't keep a lid on the complexity of this code you're going to drown in it. Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. With those you have patterns you could follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Your form method is set to "post" and you verify the button click with `if(isset($_POST['Buy'])){` however when creating your SQL statement you are using `$item_code` which is previously set by `$item_code = $_GET['item_code'];`. The `$_GET` variable will always be empty during post requests.

If you are using both get and post requests to use this interface, then you should change to `$_REQUEST`, otherwise you would want to consolidate by always using `$_POST`;